# Calculating cumulating probabilities

Tags: random, probability

I'm sorry if this is the wrong place for this query.  If it is, perhaps someone could direct me to the right place.

I have a program that has a bunch of objects (say n) to process and a process that iteratively processes one object.

At each iteration I have one less objects processed.  I want to check if I need more objects.

If there are 100 objects or more, I have plenty.  When there are less than 100 objects, say, I would like to get some more objects at a probability (P) that is roughly zero at 100 and 1 at 0 objects.

P(n) = 1 - (n/100)

If I just do a random calculation based on this probability then over time I get a cumulative probability that is the product of the series of probabilities which is not the same as the formula above.

If the probability added each time, I would get an integral of P(n), but since it is an accumulating product, what is the new function and how to calculate the function?

So I would like the total probability up till now to equal that formula.  How do I work out the probability I need at the current iteration?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to compute -- the long-term average number of items in the queue? The probability that there will be `n` objects waiting to be processed after `k` iterations? Whatever you are trying to find, it can probably be found by modeling this as a Markov chain. Where the state is the number of objects that are currently waiting to be processed.

Comment: It's much simpler than that.  I process an object, then I get more objects with a probability based on the number of unprocessed objects.  The less objects left, the higher the probability of getting more.

Answer (score 0):

I realised after some thought that the answer is a simple integral, because the probability at each step is not independent, if I get more objects, the probability resets, if I don't get more objects the probability is the sum of all the times before that I didn't get more objects.